# Laravel livewire - Data not save in the database with pivot

Tags: laravel, crud, laravel-livewire, livewires, laravel-livewire-wiremodel

I'm new to livewire and currently I created a simple crud that can save the student data.
My database schema are student table, families table and family_student table.

**Student TAble**

```
Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('middle_name');
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->date('dob');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**Families Table**

```
Schema::create('families', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('f_last_name');
            $table->string('f_middle_name');
            $table->string('f_first_name');
            $table->string('f_occupation');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**Family Student Table**

```
 Schema::create('family_student', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('student_id')->constrained();
            $table->foreignId('family_id')->constrained();
            $table->boolean('isParent')->default(0);
            $table->boolean('guardianStudentLiving')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

In the livewire part I populate 3 sets of input that and all data will be save in the same columns.

**LIVEWIRE**

```
    public $last_name;
    public $middle_name;
    public $first_name;
    public $dob;
    public $f_last_name;
    public $f_middle_name;
    public $f_first_name;
    public $f_occupation;
    public $isParent = null;
    public $guardianStudentLiving = null;

    public $getData;

    public $parentCollections = [];
    public $setFields = 3;

    // Set sang rules for validation
    protected $rules = [
        'last_name' => ['required'],
        'middle_name' => ['required'],
        'first_name' => ['required'],
        'dob' => ['required'],
        'f_last_name.*' => ['required'],
        'f_middle_name.*' => ['required'],
        'f_first_name.*' => ['required'],
        'f_occupation.*' => ['required'],
        'guardianStudentLiving.*' => ['required'],
    ];
    // relatime validation trigger sang update function
    public function updated($propertyName){
       $this->validateOnly($propertyName);
    }

    // save data in db
    public function store(){
        $studentData = ModelsStudent::create([
            'last_name' => $this->last_name,
            'middle_name' => $this->middle_name,
            'first_name' => $this->first_name,
            'dob' => $this->dob,
        ]);

        $isParent = $this->isParent != null ? 1 : 0;
        $guardianStudentLiving = $this->guardianStudentLiving  != null ? 1 : 0;

        foreach ($this->parentCollections as $key => $parentCollection) {
            $parent = ModelsFamily::create([
                ['f_last_name' => $parentCollection['f_last_name']],
                ['f_middle_name' => $parentCollection['f_middle_name']],
                ['f_first_name' => $parentCollection['f_first_name']],
                ['f_occupation' => $parentCollection['f_occupation']],
            ]);

            foreach ($parentCollection as $key => $value) {
                $value = $this->studentData->families()->attach($key,
                [
                    'isParent' => $isParent,
                    'guardianStudentLiving' => $guardianStudentLiving,
                    'created_at' => now(),
                    'updated_at' => now()
                ]);
            }
        }

        session()->flash('message','The data successfully saved!');

        $this->reset();
    }

    public function mount(){
         //get data
        $this->getData = ModelsStudent::with(['families:id,f_last_name,f_middle_name,f_first_name,f_occupation'])->select('id','first_name','middle_name','last_name')->get();

        //creating 3 sets of input fields
        for ($i=0; $i < $this->setFields; $i++) {
            $this->parentCollections[] = [
                'f_last_name' => '',
                'f_middle_name' => '',
                'f_first_name' => '',
                'occupation'    => ''
            ];
        }
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.student.student');
    }
```

**LIVEWIRE FORM**

```
    <form wire:submit.prevent='store'>
        @csrf
        @if (session()->has('message'))
            <div class="px-6 py-4 bg-blue-50 rounded-lg text-blue-500">
                {{ session('message') }}
            </div>
        @endif
        <div>
            <h5 class="text-lg mb-5">Student Information</h5>
            <div class="flex flex-row space-x-4">
                <x-label>{{ __('last name') }}</x-label>
                <x-input wire:model.lazy='last_name' name="last_name" id="last_name" type="text" required></x-input>
                <x-label>{{ __('middle name') }}</x-label>
                <x-input wire:model.lazy='middle_name' name="middle_name" id="middle_name" type="text" required></x-input>
                <x-label>{{ __('first name') }}</x-label>
                <x-input wire:model.lazy='first_name' name="first_name" id="first_name" type="text" required></x-input>
                <x-label>{{ __('date of birth') }}</x-label>
                <x-input type="date" wire:model.lazy='dob'  name="dob" id="dob" required></x-input>
            </div>
            <hr class="my-12">
            <h5 class="text-lg mb-5">Parent Information</h5>

            {{-- @for ($i = 0 ; $i < 3 ; $i++)
                <div class="flex flex-row mb-8">{{ ($i === 1) ? 'Father' : (($i === 2) ? 'Mother' : 'Guardian') }} {{ __("'s Info") }}</div>
                <livewire:student.parent-input :i="$i" :wire:key='$i'>
            @endfor --}}

                @foreach ($parentCollections as $key => $parentCollection)
                    <div class="flex flex-row mb-6">
                        <x-label class="text-bold">
                            {{ ($key === 0) ? 'Father' : (($key === 1) ? 'Mother' : 'Guardian') }} {{ __("'s Info") }} <span class="text-red-500 text-bold text-lg">*</span>
                        </x-label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="grid grid-cols-4 grid-rows-1 grid-flow-row gap-4">
                           <div>
                                <div class="flex flex-col">
                                    <x-label class="text-xs">{{ __('LAST NAME') }}</x-label>
                                    <x-input wire:key='parentCollections[{{ $key }}][ f_last_name ]' wire:model.lazy='parentCollections.{{ $key }}.f_last_name' class="mb-8" placeholder="Last name"/>
                                    @error('parentCollections.{{ $key }}.f_last_name') <span class="text-red-500 error">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
                                </div>
                           </div>
                           <div>
                                <div class="flex flex-col">
                                    <x-label class="text-xs">{{ __('MIDDLE NAME') }}</x-label>
                                    <x-input wire:key='parentCollections[{{ $key }}][ f_middle_name ]' wire:model.lazy='parentCollections.{{ $key }}.f_middle_name' class="mb-8"/>
                                    @error('f_middle_name.{{ $parentCollections }}') <span class="text-red-500 error">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
                                </div>
                           </div>
                           <div>
                                <div class="flex flex-col">
                                    <x-label class="text-xs">{{ __('FIRST NAME') }}</x-label>
                                    <x-input wire:key='parentCollections[{{ $key }}][ f_first_name ]' wire:model.lazy='parentCollections.{{ $key }}.f_first_name' class="mb-8"/>
                                </div>
                           </div>
                            <div>
                                <div class="flex flex-col">
                                    <x-label class="text-xs">{{ __('OCCUPATION') }}</x-label>
                                    <x-input wire:key='parentCollections[{{ $key }}][ f_occupation ]' wire:model.lazy='parentCollections.{{ $key }}.f_occupation' class="mb-8"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @if ($key > 1)
                            <div class="flex flex-row space-x-4 content-center">
                                <x-checkbox wire:key='guardianStudentLiving.{{ $key }}' wire:model.lazy='guardianStudentLiving.{{ $key }}' name="guardianStudentLiving.{{ $key }}" class="mb-8"/>
                                <x-label class="text-md">{{ __('Is guardian living with the student?') }}</x-label>
                            </div>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                @endforeach

            <x-button wire:submit.prevent='store' type="submit" class="mt-8">{{ __("Submit") }}</x-button>

        </div>
    </form>
```

Now my problem is, every time I save the data the only data will be save are the student data only and it dispalyed an error like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qssYW.png)

How can I save the multiple input data in the families table?

I want to save the 3 sets of families data to be save in the database at the same time is attached the pivot column.